# How to mock Axios as default export with Jest

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs

How do I mock `axios` that export as default function?

I have the api helper that generalizes api request with `axios()`

**api.js**

```
export const callApi = (endpoint, method, data = {}) => {

  return axios({
    url: endpoint,
    method,
    data
  })
  .then((response) => // handle response)
  .catch((error) => // handle error)
};
```

**api.spec.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { callApi } from './api';

describe('callApi()', () => {
  it('calls `axios()` with `endpoint`, `method` and `body`', () => {

    // mock axios()
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'default');

    const endpoint = '/endpoint';
    const method = 'post';
    const data = { foo: 'bar' };

    // call function
    callApi(endpoint, method, data);

    // assert axios()
    expect(axios.default).toBeCalledWith({ url: endpoint, method, data});
  });
});
```

**result**

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [{"data": {"foo": "bar"}, "method": "post", "url": "/endpoint"}]
But it was not called.
```

The call works fine if I mock `axios.get()` or other methods, but not for just `axios()`. I don't want to change the definition of the `callApi()` function.

How do I mock default `axios()`? What did I miss?

Comment: method accepts  `Object` like `{method: 'post'}`, but I can see you are passing it as a plain value instead of an Object.

Comment: ```return axios({
    url: endpoint,
    method: postmethod,
    data
  })```
Try with this

Comment: I don't get the comment. `callApi()` accept plain values. It then constructs the object from its plain value arguments and passes the object to `axios()`. Is that what you are trying to point out?

Comment: Yes, I don't see `method` converting into object in `callApi`.

Comment: It is the shorthand object assignment when the properties having the same name. That means `const foo = { method: method }` is the same as just `const foo = { method }`. Or if there is any point that I missed?

Comment: My bad. Missed that part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use `jest.spyOn(axios, 'default')` when you call `axios` directly (no `default`). Changing your implementation in `api.js` to be `axios.default(...args)` makes the test pass.

---

A potential change you can make is to use `jest.mock('axios')` instead of using `jest.spyOn`.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { callApi } from './api';

jest.mock('axios');

// Make sure to resolve with a promise
axios.mockResolvedValue();

describe('callApi()', () => {
  it('calls `axios()` with `endpoint`, `method` and `body`', () => {
    const endpoint = '/endpoint';
    const method = 'post';
    const data = { foo: 'bar' };

    // call function
    callApi(endpoint, method, data);

    // assert axios()
    expect(axios).toBeCalledWith({ url: endpoint, method, data});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. One problem though, `axios.mockImplementation` works fine, but I have an error on `axios.mockResolvedValue` states that `_axios2.default.mockResolvedValue is not a function`. Jest version `23.6.0`.

Comment: That function is definitely available in `23.6`. Are you using `create-react-app`? In that case you're stuck on Jest 20 until they upgrade unless you eject. If you don't use CRA I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: I'm using the boiler plate [React Slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot).

Comment: Saved my life with axios.mockResolvedValue(). The examples I found mock axios but don't mention this. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 2021. I wonder why?

Comment: @SimenB Property 'mockResolvedValue' does not exist on type 'AxiosStatic'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

For `jest 28`, at least, you can use the following:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { myModule } from '.'

jest.mock('axios')
const mockedAxios = jest.mocked(axios, true)

describe('myModule', () => {
  test('response with no errors', async () => {
    mockedAxios.mockReturnValue('SUCCESS' as any)
    ...

    expect(mockedAxios).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      URL: 'http://....',
      data: { update: 'data' },
      method: 'PUT',
      ...config
    })
  })
})
```